# Issue with using a list to populate a table in an MVC 5 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
    {
        Landbase _db = new Landbase();

        OwnerWorkingInterests workingInterests = new OwnerWorkingInterests();

        //Owner owner = new Owner();



        var query = (from wg in _db.WorkingInterestGroups
            join wi in _db.WorkingInterests on wg.Id equals wi.WorkingInterestGroupId
            join l in _db.Leases on wg.LeaseId equals l.Id
            where wi.OwnerId.Equals(Id)
            select new OwnerWorkingInterests()
            {
                LeaseId = l.Id,
                WorkingInterestAmount = wi.WorkingInterestAmount,
                WorkingInterestGroupName = wg.Name,
                ClientAlias = l.ClientAlias,
                Lessor = l.Lessor,
                Lessee = l.Lessee,
                VolDocNumber = l.VolumeDocumentNumber,
                County = l.County,
                District = l.District
            }).ToList();

        //List<string> OwnerWorkingInterest = query.ToList<string>();

        return View(query);
    }
```

I have the following code in my view:

```
        <div id="OwnerWorkingInterests" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Working Interests</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lease Id:</td>
                    <td>Working Int:</td>
                    <td>WI Group Name:</td>
                    <td>Alias:</td>
                    <td>Lessor:</td>
                    <td>Lessee:</td>
                    <td>VolPg:</td>
                    <td>County:</td>
                    <td>District0:</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var owi in OwnerWorkingInterests)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@owi.LeaseId</td>
                    <td>@owi.WorkingInterestAmount</td>
                    <td>@owi.WorkingInterestGroupName</td>
                    <td>@owi.ClientAlias</td>
                    <td>@owi.Lessor</td>
                    <td>@owi.Lessee</td>
                    <td>@owi.VolDocNumber</td>
                    <td>@owi.County</td>
                    <td>@owi.District</td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I thought this would populate the table with the proper information

This is the viewmodel:

```
namespace LandPortal.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class WorkingInterest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    [Column("WorkingInterest")]
    public decimal? WorkingInterestAmount { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45)]
    public string ModifyUser { get; set; }

    public Guid? CreateUserId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ModifyUserId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }

    public int? WorkingInterestGroupId { get; set; }

    public WorkingInterestGroup WorkingInterestGroup { get; set; }

    public decimal? ORRI { get; set; }

    public int? ORRIOwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }


}
```

}

So what happens is it throws a very vague error when I run it in debugger.  It literally just says Error: An error occurred when processing your request.  So I am assuming that the list is populating but not working in the foreach in the view.  I could be wrong at this point.

Here are the model directives for the view

```
@using LandPortal.Models
@using LandPortal.ViewModels
@using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
@model LandPortal.Models.Owner
```

Comment: The foreach is referencing a variable, OwnerWorkingInterests. Where is this variable defined? I don't see it in the model.

Comment: The OwnerWorkingInterests is the ViewModel that stores the result of the linq query.

Comment: Does your compiler know that? You might be getting a compile on demand error and that's why you see your generic exception.

Comment: Honestly, I do not know I am pretty green with linq.

Comment: Ok, you should define a strong model and bind to that, not return a dynamic object. It's a lot easier to debug. What's your view's Model directive look  like?

Comment: So should I use a partial view instead?  The foreach statement is part of a view that already has a strongly typed model.

Comment: Sorry I missed the second half of the question.  I added it to the original question

Comment: Okay, so if your view expects a model of Owner, but your query isn't returning that, that's your problem. I'll post a little example in a few.

Answer (score 0):

If the view expects a model that is of type LandPortal.Models.Owner, and Index returns an entire ActionResult, then Index needs to return a model of that type.

A tiny example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int Id)
{
    Landbase _db = new Landbase();
    Owner owner = new Owner();

    // some query has to set properties on this owner object
    // let's pretend there's a property named OwnerWorkingInterests on it

    owner.OwnerWorkingInterests = query.ToList();  // you will have to define "query" and set it similar to how you already did

    return View(owner);
}
```

Now your view can access the property on the model as so

```
@foreach (var owi in Model.OwnerWorkingInterests)
```

This is a very high level example, but I see you have a partial class and mentioned partial views in your comment. If you have a large view and are trying to break up a query into pieces, that can be done with PartialViewResult and will be a bit different from this.

Comment: So basically I have to add an ICollection to my owner model?  To reference the WorkingInterest view model correct

Comment: Yes, if you don't already have a collection property in there that you want to use. Conversely, you could use partial view result and have a method that just returns your collection, but that's beyond the scope of this particular question.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how new you are, but just to be clear, this way wipes out the entire page and replaces it. You will lose whatever other properties might have been on your model before.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out and see what happens